# Best way to create widget-like ajax page sections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So, I have a page that is made up of 4 different AJAX containers (meaning they are populated with HTML via AJAX). I have an attachment section that refreshes the section whenever a new upload has been performed.

Currently I have a DIV that gets replaced with the content I want, then when I execute some kind of AJAX POST action, it returns with the updated HTML content. In one case, I have an AJAX section that includes an AJAX section that includes and AJAX section. It is a 'quote' screen with a 'location' section which populates with a page for each location attached to the quote...and each location has a 'line item' section that populates with a list of current line items assigned to that location. I have an AJAXform attached to each location that refreshes the line item list when an item is added. Also, I have a form attached to the quote page that refreshes the location list when a location is added.

```
<!-- Quote page -->
<div id="locations>
    <!-- AJAX page listing locations -->
</div>
<form id="ajax-form-for-adding-locations">
    <input id="location-name" type="text"/>
</form>
```

---

```
<!-- Location page -->
<div id="line items">
    <!-- AJAX page listing line items for this location -->
</div>
<form id="ajax-form-for-adding-line-items">
    <input id="item-name" type="text"/>
</form>
```

The nested AJAX sections seems a little excessive to me. Is there a better way to set this up?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your explaination, but is it within the scope of your application to request both the locations and its line items with the same call? This would eliminate the nested ajax calls.

Comment: Currently I have the quote page getting a list of locations, then each location page is responsible for retrieving the items. I'm not sure if that is more or less efficient than calling locations and items in the same call. I'm just thinking of Web parts with .Net and Google Gadgets and how they can be placed anywhere in an application, passed some parameters, and you're up and running with a consistent AJAX-based view.

Comment: If I understand this correctly...Why can't you just return the list of locations with their info?  The server is already aware of the information it needs to send. Why ask it again for the information it could have already sent?

Comment: We want to reload the item list within each location via AJAX. Are you suggesting that when an item is added to a location to just reload the location area that is already linked to the item list? My primary concern is that the location "widget" has to be self-contained for re-usability in other parts of the application meaning that the form elements should be inside the location area too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best, cleanest, most extensible and most future proof way to tackle this kind of one-page app design which is heavily based on ajax would be to use one of the [javascript MVC libraries](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/20-javascript-frameworks-worth-checking-out/).

Personally I recommend you the [backbonejs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) - it has a great community, is actively developed, lightweight and fast to learn enough to be able to build quality application in no time.

Check the [website](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) and look at the example apps using backbone, go through the short (but fully covering the code) documentation and have a look at the example todo app. You can also [check the wiki page on github](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Tutorials,-blog-posts-and-example-sites) for even more resources and examples/tutorials

We are using it at our company after trying some other options before and we <3 it to the point that it's hard to believe!

Oh, and you mentioned in tags jquery - BackboneJS plays super nicely with jQuery (and CoffeeScript, and whatever else... it's pure love :) !)

Comment: I was thinking of using something like ExtJS, but backbone.jr looks very clean! I hadn't really thought of doing a JS MVC on top of my .Net M(V)C 3.

Comment: Backbone works best and is designed for working with REST API architecture on server side, if you don't have that adapting it might be a bit of hacking! We are using rails in our project and it all fits so well that I melt when I think about it!